# How to find & remove duplicates in data frames?

Tags: r

I have the follwing data frame which happens to be NBA draft data:

```
 draft_year draft_round teamid playerid draft_from
 1961           1         Bos    Pol1      Nan
 2001           1         LA     Ben2      Cal
 1967           2         Min    Mac2      Nan
 2001           1         LA     Ben2      Cal
 2000           1         C      Sio1      Bud
 2000           1         C      Gio1      Bud
```

I would like to find & remove only those rows with duplicates in playerid. For obvious reasons, the remaining duplicates have a meaningful purpose and must be kept.

Comment: Your example data is not so good, because a simple `unique(df)` will also return the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` package you have a `by` parameter in the `unique` function

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by = "playerid")
#    draft_year draft_round teamid playerid draft_from
# 1:       1961           1    Bos     Pol1        Nan
# 2:       2001           1     LA     Ben2        Cal
# 3:       1967           2    Min     Mac2        Nan
# 4:       2000           1      C     Sio1        Bud
# 5:       2000           1      C     Gio1        Bud
```

Comment: @ David is there also a way to account for duplicates in time series. imagine the above data frame but instead of draft_year you have year_played. so for obvious reasons there must be duplicates of one player playing for one or different teams during her carreer. but how would I detect a duplicate of a player mistakenly counted twice in one year.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But you can add as many variables as you want into `by`, for example `unique(setDT(df), by = c("year_played, "playerid"))`

Comment: To extend to multiple variables in base R, you would do: `dat[!duplicated(dat[c("playerid","draft_year")]),]`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `duplicated` or `unique()`

`new_df <- df[!duplicated( df$playerid), ]`

Comment: Doesn't this only return a vector?

Comment: thats return only one column :)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying in my local, I didn't use R for sometime. But you can achieve by using `duplicated()` and `unique()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 unique(df, group_by="playerid")
 #  draft_year draft_round teamid playerid draft_from
 #1       1961           1    Bos     Pol1        Nan
 #2       2001           1     LA     Ben2        Cal
 #3       1967           2    Min     Mac2        Nan
 #5       2000           1      C     Sio1        Bud
 #6       2000           1      C     Gio1        Bud
```

Or

```
 df %>%
 group_by(playerid) %>%
 filter(row_number()==1)
```